# Running a python .py from lighttable, ctrl+shift+enter : nothing happens

Tags: python, ubuntu, lighttable

A python code is loaded in lighttable 0.4.11.
ctrl+shift+enter doesn't run the code.

From the connect tab, one can see that the code is connected to ipython:
[image]

Comment: did you lookup the [github issues](https://github.com/Kodowa/Light-Table-Playground/issues?page=1&state=open) or the [lighttable discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/light-table-discussion)? chances are this has been reported.

Comment: Same problem than: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/ExcOpPDNLWY. Doesn't seem to be fixed

Comment: Do you have a console open?

Answer (score 1):

with version 0.64, on windows 7x64, this problem is still happen, but using command (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**) and adding new connection (e.g. add Python27 path instead of Python33) helps the problem.

[image]